# Are there puzzles that take into account a specific time / day in the year?

Tags: puzzle-creation

I'm looking to create a type of puzzle that involves the passage of time where the puzzle can only be solved a specific times / days in a year. It could use environmental surroundings like the sun/ weather/seasons/stars/etc. Or it can be linked to something "virtual" that resides on the internet. Has there been any type of puzzles that used these elements?

Comment: The Moon-letters written on the Thrór's Map predicted that on Durin's Day the last light of the Sun as night fell would reveal the secret door into the Lonely Mountain.

Comment: Are we talking about this being done in real life?  A few that come to mind - A ray of sunlight has to hit a certain spot in National Treasure, Raiders of the Lost Ark, and in an episode of Avatar the last Airbender as well as in the Hobbit reference above.

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is "yes". Is there something more that you wanted from this?

Comment: Off the top of my head: You could do it by writing a website that displayed a different image each day, and have one of them be related to a puzzle that drops a breadcrumb leading to it, as well as a hint about the day you need to visit on.

Comment: As asked, this is either a yes/no question (the answer, as noted, is "yes", but that's unlikely to be useful to you), or a request for a list of instances of such puzzles — and requests for lists are generally off-topic almost everywhere on Stack Exchange, including here (see [this help page](/help/dont-ask) for more about this).

Answer (score 3):

This scene from Indiana jones springs to mind. The puzzle can only be solved at a certain time of day when the light is shining through the hole and you have the special staff. [Here's a link to the wiki page](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Room)

[image: This Scene from Indiana jones springs to mind]